# Did Bible Characters Typically Drink Water?

Tags: food, tanach, science, water

I've always heard that in the medieval era, people drank dilute beer all the time because the water wasn't safe.

We find all over Tanach accounts of people "eating bread and drinking water." Was that actually plain ol' water, or is it generic for "liquids"? (And was the water less-unsafe in the Biblical period, or did they just get sick often?)

Comment: Did they have wells dug down to the beer-table?

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to first ask if people really drank dilute beer because water wasn't safe, before asking if Water doesn't mean water.